# What should be set for contentType if json object is sent in response

Tags: json, contenttype

I am making an ajax call , here I am not sending any data I am fetching the data in response whcih was already set by previous request. On the server side I am building jsonObject and sending , what is the contentType I should use application/x-json or text/x-json as all my datas are text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy to search for you, but anyway:
[What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

(**TL;DR:** The MIME media type for JSON text is `application/json`)

Comment: yes I came acros that SO question but I was confused as  one answer mentions depending on what your application sends , if it is text "text/x-json" this can be used.

Answer (score 1):

On server side you should return :**MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON** (if you are using jersey java).

On client side(js) you should use **datatype:"JSON".**
(Not content type , because content type is used to specify type of data you are sending to server and datatype is the type of data you are expecting from server in response).

Example:

**1. Server Side (jersey java- JAX-RS):**

```
@GET
@Path("/yourpath.json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public returnSomething functionName(){
    ...
    ...
}
```

**2. Client Side (ajax call):**

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: ajaxUrl,
datatype:"JSON",
success: function(jsonData){
    //Do something
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    //handle connection errors
}});
```

This will work even if your json contains normal text.